# Connect Android Studio to MySQL without JSON

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect my Android Studio to my local MYSQL Server database using JDBC but I am getting error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Can someone give me a quick sample program using the JDBC?

Comment: JSON is not need to create MySQL connection from Android program.

Comment: Thanks for reply - I m don't wont to use JSON that it why I am use Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); but it's is working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using php to connect to mySQL or you are trying to connect to mySQL directly from your app? If you are trying to connect directly, then this is a very bad idea, as your app will have be used by many users and ur app will have CRUD permission. You should create a server side class and try to connect via that class.

If you are using your android device as debugger, you will need to use your pc's ip address as the link to your localhost.
Like: http://192.168.1.5/folder/somefile.php 
where you will parse the data and is much secure than your previous attempt.

Useful links: 
[Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks - I have Android app connected to Mysql using Php & JSON but it's very compilicated , I am trying to connect directly without JSON

Comment: Yeh unfortunately, is there any idea to connect to mysql without using  JSON.

Comment: People usually don't connect directly to mySQL without using JSON. I have never heard anyone using mySQL without JSON or any other formats.